# Will it impair the performance to explicitly feed data to 'tf.data.Dataset'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm implementing an RL algorithm and using [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)(with [prefetch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch)) to feed data to the neural network. However, in order to interact with the environment, I have to explicitly feed data through `feed_dict` to take action. I'm wondering if using `feed_dict` with `Dataset` would impair the speed.

Here's a simplified version of my code

```py
# code related to Dataset
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(buffer, sample_types, sample_shapes)
ds = ds.prefetch(5)
iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
samples = iterator.get_next(name='samples')
# pass samples to network
```

```py
# network training, no feed_dict is needed because of Dataset
sess.run([self.opt_op])
```

```py
# run the actor network to choose an action at the current state.
# manually feed the current state to samples
# will this impair the performance?
action = sess.run(self.action, feed_dict={samples['state']: state})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is nothing wrong with mixing Dataset and feed_dict. If the state that you provide to feed_dict is large, it might lead to underutilized GPU depending on the size of the data. But it would in no way be related to Dataset being used.

One of the reasons Dataset API exists is to avoid model starvation and improve GPU utilization during training. The starvation might happen for reasons of data being copied from one locations to another: disk to memory, memory to GPU memory, you name it. Dataset tries to start executing bulky IO operations early enough to avoid starving the model when the time comes to process next batch. So, basically, Datasets tries to reduce time between batches.

In your case you probably don't loose any performance from using feed_dict. It seems that you break the execution by environment interaction anyhow (therefore, possibly underutilizing the GPU).

If you would like to be sure, time your performance when you are feeding actual state with feed_dict and than replace state usage with a constant tensor and compare the speed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I forgot to mention that the network training actually happens in a background thread. I'm afraid that when I use feed_dict to take action in the main thread. The prefetch data in the background will be missing, thereby impairing the learning speed.

Comment: It should not make a huge difference in your case. The devil is in the details and actually it would depend on the exact setup of your multythread workers, size of the data state holds and where the tensors immediately using the state lay. The best way to sort it out is to replace your "state" placeholder with a constant and compare the throughput